# will windows application created using visual studio 2008 will work on winXP with out .net framework

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have made a small windows application with visual studio 2008 ,its working properly with win 7,but when i tried it in an another machine which is running in win xp it showed error. I googled and found that,the win xp machine what i have used does not have a .net framework.My question is that is their any way to make an application using vb 2008 which can be run in win xp computers which doesnt have a .net framework (other than virutlalisation) or to incorporate .net framework in the application.

*I am sorry for asking this question,i know its "dumb" question but i am new to vb.net
Advance thanks

Comment: The rule in this site is, that you indicate the usefull answer to your question. Until now you did not accept ANY answer, so why should we (community) bother to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You must have to install the appropriate version of .net framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can make .netframework 2.0 application using visual studio 2008. Select . net framework 2.0 on opening visual studio 2008. This application will work in windows xp without installing any . net framework.